# Different data size with write.table function in R

Tags: r, filesize

I am just confused...when i use the write.table function in R, i.e.
`write.table(Beta_F, file = "Beta_F_WS1_WS12.tsv", sep ="\t", col.names = T, row.names = T)`
I figured out that the size of the written data differ sometimes. I had 2 almost equivalent tables, and after the writing process i noticed that the size was really differing (600MB vs 300MB).
So after writing the table again it suddenly was also about 600MB. Does anybody had this issue as well? My OS is Windows11, I work with R Studio.

I rewrote the tables again and checked the size in the folder

Comment: Please provide some example data and code to reproduce your problem. What do you mean by "Almost identical table..." maybe the data type is different, or the arguments you use for saving the two tables are different? Challenging to say without any examples or data.

Comment: Are you sure that you are writing the same `Beta_F` object, and not changing the object that you are about to write?